# javascript - menu opens on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Good afternoon

I'm using a menu with rings on my site, but this one opens when the site loads. I tried to toggle code with javascript but without success.
The menu can only open when the button is clicked.

I leave here all the menu code (CSS) to make it easier to see the problem.

(Sorry for my bad English)
Thanks in advance.

```js
toggle = document.querySelectorAll(".toggle")[0];
nav = document.querySelectorAll("nav")[0];
toggle_open_text = '&#9776;';
toggle_close_text = '&#10006;';

nav.classList.toggle('open');

toggle.addEventListener('click', function() {
 nav.classList.toggle('open');
 
  if (nav.classList.contains('open')) {
    toggle.innerHTML = toggle_close_text;
  } else {
    toggle.innerHTML = toggle_open_text;
  }
}, false);

setTimeout(function(){
 nav.classList.toggle('open'); 
}, 800);
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web");
/*html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: beige;
  font-family: Alegreya Sans, sans-serif;
}
*/
nav {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(25px, -25px, 0);
          transform: translate3d(25px, -25px, 0);
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.3, 1.4, 0.5, 0.9);
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.3, 1.4, 0.5, 0.9);
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.3, 1.4, 0.5, 0.9), -webkit-transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.3, 1.4, 0.5, 0.9);
}
nav.open {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
          transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
nav.top-right {
  top: -140px;
  right: -140px;
}

.disc {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  font: 25px Titillium Web, sans-serif;
  line-height: 40px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  border-radius: 250px;
  -webkit-transform: scale3d(0.5, 0.5, 0.5) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 190deg);
          transform: scale3d(0.5, 0.5, 0.5) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 190deg);
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: opacity 0.5s, -webkit-transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.3, 1.4, 0.5, 0.9);
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.3, 1.4, 0.5, 0.9), opacity 0.5s;
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.3, 1.4, 0.5, 0.9), opacity 0.5s, -webkit-transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.3, 1.4, 0.5, 0.9);
}
.disc div {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
          transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.open .disc {
  pointer-events: auto;
  opacity: 1;
}

.l1 {
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  background: #627ca9;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}
.open .l1 {
  transition-delay: 0s;
  -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 190deg);
          transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 190deg);
  opacity: 1;
}
.open .l1:hover {
  background: shade(#627ca9, 90%);
  color: #627ca9;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}
.open .l1:active {
  background: shade(#627ca9, 50%);
  color: #627ca9;
}
.open .l1.toggle {
  -webkit-transform: scale3d(0.9, 0.9, 0.9) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 10deg);
          transform: scale3d(0.9, 0.9, 0.9) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 10deg);
}

.l2 {
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  right: 50px;
  bottom: 50px;
  background: #627ca9;
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
}
.open .l2 {
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
  -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 190deg);
          transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 190deg);
  opacity: 1;
}
.open .l2:hover {
  background: shade(#627ca9, 90%);
  color: #627ca9;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}
.open .l2:active {
  background: shade(#627ca9, 50%);
  color: #627ca9;
}
.open .l2.toggle {
  -webkit-transform: scale3d(0.9, 0.9, 0.9) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 10deg);
          transform: scale3d(0.9, 0.9, 0.9) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 10deg);
}

.l3 {
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  right: 100px;
  bottom: 100px;
  background: #627ca9;
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}
.open .l3 {
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
  -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 190deg);
          transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 190deg);
  opacity: 1;
}
.open .l3:hover {
  background: shade(#627ca9, 90%);
  color: #627ca9;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}
.open .l3:active {
  background: shade(#627ca9, 50%);
  color: #627ca9;
}
.open .l3.toggle {
  -webkit-transform: scale3d(0.9, 0.9, 0.9) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 10deg);
          transform: scale3d(0.9, 0.9, 0.9) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 10deg);
}

.l4 {
  top: 150px;
  left: 150px;
  right: 150px;
  bottom: 150px;
  background: #627ca9;
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
}
.open .l4 {
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 190deg);
          transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 190deg);
  opacity: 1;
}
.open .l4:hover {
  background: shade(#627ca9, 90%);
  color: #627ca9;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}
.open .l4:active {
  background: shade(#627ca9, 50%);
  color: #627ca9;
}
.open .l4.toggle {
  -webkit-transform: scale3d(0.9, 0.9, 0.9) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 10deg);
          transform: scale3d(0.9, 0.9, 0.9) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 10deg);
}

.l5 {
  top: 200px;
  left: 200px;
  right: 200px;
  bottom: 200px;
  background: #627ca9;
  transition-delay: 0.4s;
}
.open .l5 {
  transition-delay: 0.4s;
  -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 190deg);
          transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 190deg);
  opacity: 1;
}
.open .l5:hover {
  background: shade(#627ca9, 90%);
  color: #627ca9;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}
.open .l5:active {
  background: shade(#627ca9, 50%);
  color: #627ca9;
}
.open .l5.toggle {
  -webkit-transform: scale3d(0.9, 0.9, 0.9) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 10deg);
          transform: scale3d(0.9, 0.9, 0.9) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 10deg);
}

.toggle {
  line-height: 100px;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100px;
  background: #627ca9;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: none;
          transform: none;
  pointer-events: auto;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}
.open .toggle {
  -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 0deg);
          transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 0deg);
}
.toggle:hover {
  background: shade(#627ca9, 90%);
  color: #627ca9;
}
.toggle:active {
  background: shade(#627ca9, 50%);
  color: rgba(255, 215, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.9);
          transform: scale(0.9);
  transition-duration: 0s;
}
```

```html
<nav style="opacity:0.9;" class="top-right open">
        <a style="color:#FFFFFF" href="index.html" class="disc l1">
          <div>#ROCKON</div>
        </a>
        <a style="color:#FFFFFF" href="player-hd/top10.html" class="disc l2">
          <div>VOTE</div>
        </a>
        <a style="color:#FFFFFF" href="player-hd/podcasts.html" class="disc l3">
          <div>PODCASTS</div>
        </a>
        <a style="color:#FFFFFF" href="player-hd/listen.html" class="disc l4">
          <div>LIVE</div>
        </a>
        <a style="color:#FFFFFF; font-size: 30px;" class="disc l5 toggle">
          &#9776;
        </a>
      </nav>
```

Comment: Your code seems to work fine in the demo, it automatically opens the menu after a small delay when I load it.  Also, this menu looks really cool!

Comment: yes, it looks like a disk and it's a simple menu for some inputs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are adding the class `.open` with a `setTimeout`.

Remove that `setTimeout` and you'll be ok

Answer (score 1):

Just simply remove that:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    nav.classList.toggle('open');   
}, 800);
```